# Issue while storing encoded string in database

Tags: c#, sql, character-encoding, binary, ascii

I have code that encodes a string. I'm using that code to encode a string and store it in my database. Issue occurs while I fetch the encoded string that I stored in my database and decode it again, some characters are getting missed while decoding.

This is the encoding and decoding logic, I'm using a normal "insert into" statement to store the encoded string.

```
private char Encode(char character)
    {
        return (char)(character >> 7 | character << 9);
    }

private char Decode(char character)
    {
        return (char)(character >> 9 | character << 7);
    }
```

There is no issue in the encoding/decoding logic because if I directly decode an encoded string(without storing and fetching from db), everything works fine.

Example: Assume I'm encoding "gmail", it gets stored in database as "츀�숀툀�", if I decode this, the output is "gai".

I read that the symbol "�" appears if an invalid (non-UTF-8) character is saved in the database. How do I prevent this?

Comment: Maybe you should store the data as binary in database if possible?

Comment: I agree, some other format that the db can handle.

Comment: @jdl134679 Is there no other way? Is it possible to change collation of the database?

Comment: Collation has nothing to do with this - that's for sort orders based on various different charactersets, it has nothing to do with the engine's ability to store chars outside of it's range (which seems to be what you're dealing with).

Comment: On second thought... in MySQL you can manage the charsets and collations as two separate things (which they are).  Searches for T-SQL (which I presume you're using) are returning nothing on charsets (says based on datatype, which makes sense if you go with binary).  I don't think you have much control over that, especially considering that this is a custom encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the data within the [binary datatype](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx). This should solve your problem! I hope you can change the type of the column.